# Помогите пожалуйста. Java, client-server

Tags: веб-программирование, android, java, сервер

Требуется создать клиент-серверное приложение (android-java). С клиентом все понятно, а вот с сервером ничего не понятно. Какой проект надо создать в эклипсе, для данного приложения. Приложение чат, т.е. серверная часть принимает и отсылает сообщения.

Comment: http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-jdk-ide-tutorials/253-beginners-eclipse-tutorial-how-run-first-java-application-eclipse.html

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/

Использую для реализации серверной части.

Comment: Необязательно jee использовать можно запускать в сервлет-контейнерах типа tomcat, jetty.

Comment: ещё SOAP посоветуйте. Веб-сервис для чата - это конечно круто (круче только xml-rpc), но нафига это для чата?

обычный блокирующий tcp-сервер в виде консольного приложения - за глаза и за уши. Для эстетов - java+netty.

Comment: обычный блокирующий tcp-сервер в виде консольного приложения - т.е. обычный java проект в эклипсе? допустим написал, а дальше с ним что делать, чтобы запустить на томкате например?

Comment: А что про них поподробнее рассказывать?  Пишите сервлеты которые будут обрабатывать ваши запросы и загружаете их в tomcat. Собственно всё

Comment: томкат же вроде только war файлы принимает? Просто непонятно, сервлет - это любое приложение работающее на сервере (если я правильно понял). В гугле куча примеров по созданию сервлета для браузера, я не могу это сопоставить со своей задачей.

Comment: эм. Не увидел комментов выше. Да я пишу веб-сервисы для андроид приложений.

Comment: И? как посоветуете мне узнать как это делается?

Comment: Для начала можно перейти по ссылке попробовать накидать проект. Запустить его. Попробовать посылать, получать сообщения в браузере.

Comment: а в чем отличие реализации сервлета для браузера и сервлета для клиента?

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял ─ если чат по wi-fi то сервер не нужен, если все же нужен сервер то пишите на то что лучше знаете, я обычно пишу на php, но сейчас все больше смотрю в сторону python.

---

[java ee](https://www.google.md/search?q=java+ee+chat+&oq=java+ee+chat+&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.9939j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: требуется написать на java

Comment: чат не по wi-fi

Comment: ссыль на гуггл не от "остроумия" а просто как направление в котором стоит копать

Answer (score 0):

Веб сервер на JAVA для чата? Я бы выбрал сервлет-контейнер на Tomcat. Относительно легко писать, есть примеры и [туториалы](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseWTP/article.html), [еще туториалы](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/index.html), [больше туториалов](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIvlWrhY50o), можно писать как на JSP так и самой джаве. Единственное что, лично мне эклипс для этой цели показался неудобным. Netbeans в разы легче настроить, хотя это мое субъективное мнение.
Кроме того, немного погуглив вообще можно найти открытый код [готового чата](http://www.web-tech-india.com/software/jsp_chat.php). Если хочется что-то свое писать, можно разобраться в исходниках.